# Use md-grid-list inside md-grid-tile

Tags: angular-material2

In the [plunkr](https://material.angular.io/components/grid-list/overview), I have changed my `grid-list-overview-example.html` from this

```html
<md-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="2:1">
    <md-grid-tile>1</md-grid-tile>
    <md-grid-tile>2</md-grid-tile>
    <md-grid-tile>3</md-grid-tile>
    <md-grid-tile>4</md-grid-tile>
</md-grid-list>
```

To this:

```html
<md-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="2:1">
     <md-grid-tile>1</md-grid-tile>
     <md-grid-tile>2</md-grid-tile>
     <md-grid-tile>3</md-grid-tile>
     <md-grid-tile>
           <md-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="2:1">
                 <md-grid-tile>1</md-grid-tile>
                 <md-grid-tile>2</md-grid-tile>
             <md-grid-tile>3</md-grid-tile>
             <md-grid-tile>4</md-grid-tile>
       </md-grid-list>
     </md-grid-tile>
</md-grid-list>
```

Ideally, there should be tiles numbered 1,2,3,4 in the 4th tile of parent grid but all the tiles of child grid are set to width 0.

Is there anything extra needed to be done here?

There are workarounds but I am looking for a standard solution.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like nesting grid-lists isn't intended by the [specs](https://material.io/guidelines/components/grid-lists.html). Thus, what you are trying to accomplish won't be easy. Putting your inner grid-list in a separate component looks like a clean workaround and will most likely work (untested).

Also, it seems like [these guys](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular-material2/EO4ODHNWmTM) figured out another kind of [workaround](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZcpLQDQciOGzuQMh4GnM?p=preview) that worked for angularjs by using flexbox.

```
    <md-grid-list flex md-cols-sm="1" md-cols-md="2" md-cols-gt-md="6"
        md-row-height-gt-md="1:1" md-row-height="4:3" md-gutter="8px"
        md-gutter-gt-sm="4px" class="gridList" layout="row">
        <md-grid-tile md-colspan="1" md-colspan-sm="1" class="gridTile">
            <md-grid-list flex md-cols-md="6" md-row-height-md="1:1" md-gutter="4px"
              md-rows-md="4" layout-fill>
              <md-grid-tile md-colspan="1" md-rowspan="1"  layout="col" 
                class="flexTile">
                Tile
              </md-grid-tile>
              <md-grid-tile md-colspan="1" md-rowspan="1"  layout="col"
                class="flexTile">
                Tile
              </md-grid-tile>
              <md-grid-tile md-colspan="1" md-rowspan="1"  layout="col"
                class="flexTile">
                Tile
              </md-grid-tile>
              <md-grid-tile md-colspan="1" md-rowspan="1"  layout="col"
                class="flexTile">
                Tile
              </md-grid-tile>
              <md-grid-tile md-colspan="1" md-rowspan="1"  layout="col"
                class="flexTile">
                Tile
              </md-grid-tile>
              <md-grid-tile md-colspan="1" md-rowspan="1"  layout="col"
                class="flexTile">
                Tile
              </md-grid-tile>
              <md-grid-tile md-colspan="1" md-rowspan="1"  layout="col"
                class="flexTile">
                Tile
              </md-grid-tile>
            </md-grid-list>
            <md-grid-tile-footer><h3>Cluster name</h3></md-grid-tile-footer>
        </md-grid-tile>
    </md-grid-list>
```